# Missing piece? Own rock paper scissor game

Tags: javascript

Not printing the winner in Rock,Paper,Scissor game. For some reason I cannot get my function DeclareWinner to return any of the strings I have created.

After I did a short test where I put a string outside of my if/else statements I managed to get a print. It seems that my returns are stuck in the local scope and does therefore not get printed.

```
var weapon = "rock"

function Userchoice(weapon){
    if (weapon === "rock" || weapon === "paper" || weapon === "scissor") {
        return weapon
    }
    else {
        return "Invalid Choice";
    }
}
function Computerchoice(){
    var Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (Number === 0) {
        return "rock";
    }
    else if (Number === 1) {
        return "paper";
    }
    else if (Number === 2) {
        return "scissor";
    }
}

function DeclareWinner(Userchoice, Computerchoice){
    if (Userchoice === Computerchoice){
        return "Tiebreak";
    }
    else if (Userchoice === "rock" && Computerchoice === "scissor"){
        return "User wins";
    }
    else if (Userchoice === "rock" && Computerchoice === "paper"){
        return "Computer wins";
    }
    else if (Userchoice === "paper" && Computerchoice === "rock"){
        return "User wins";
    }
    else if (Userchoice === "paper" && Computerchoice === "scissor"){
        return "Computer wins";
    }
    else if (Userchoice === "scissor" && Computerchoice === "rock"){
        return "Computer wins";
    }
    else if (Userchoice === "scissor" && Computerchoice === "paper"){
        return "User wins";
    }   

}

console.log(Userchoice(weapon));
console.log(Computerchoice());
console.log(DeclareWinner(Userchoice, Computerchoice));
```

The expectation of console.log(DeclareWinner(Userchoice, Computerchoice)); is to print who is the winner.

(ps. I know there are several other rock paper scissor games who are more technical, I just wanted to try and create my own without specific guidance)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try console.log inside each of your functions to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the correct arguments to your function. `Userchoice` and `Computerchoice` are both references to the corresponding functions and do not represent the (string) results of your previous function calls as you might expect.

You can easily verify this by adding a `console.log(Userchoice)`, which prints:

```
function Userchoice(weapon){if(weapon==="rock"||weapon==="paper"||weapon==="scissor"){return weapon;}else{return"Invalid Choice";}}
```

You want to store the results of the function calls before printing and pass them to `DeclareWinner`.

Relevant part:

```
// Your unchanged code
// ...
let userchoice = Userchoice(weapon);
let computerchoice = Computerchoice();
console.log(userchoice);
console.log(computerchoice);
console.log(DeclareWinner(userchoice, computerchoice));
```

As a side note: Variable and method names usually start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very simply explained! :-)